# How to access Resource Environment Entry from Spring?

Tags: spring-properties

Can you use SPEL in spring to access a Resource Environment Entries custom properties? Or would you use  configured with a jndi look-up to the resource provider referenceable?

**Container Details** Websphere

**Resource Environment Provider:** provider

**Referenceables:** com.ibm.acme.ree.lib.ConfigNoCache

**Resource environment JNDI Name:** rep/provider/TestEntry/ResourceReference

**Custom Property:** mqPort

**Example**
**Configuration Within ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml**

```
    <session name="testBean">
    <resource-env-ref name="config"
        binding-name="rep/provider/TestEntry/ResourceReference" />
</session>
```

Trying something like this to load the resource environment reference so I use a place holder in spring.

```
<bean id="envConfig" class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <!-- add JNDI based properties exposed by the container -->
   <property name="properties">
        <bean class="java.util.Properties">
            <constructor-arg>
                <map>
                    <entry key="mqPort">
                        <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:rep/provider/TestEntry/ResourceReference"/>
                    </entry>
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Reference Article doing it the old way:**
https://blogs.perficient.com/ibm/2012/05/01/using-wps-style-resource-environment-providers-with-spring/

Comment: Are you using maven like biuld tool?

Comment: Nope. Just trying to access the resource environment entry from spring so I use the properties. I thought I could use systemProperties SPEL reference but doesn't seem to work.